# How to make a SQL query for last transaction of every account where last_transaction amout is 500?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Say I have a table "transactions" that has columns "acct_id" "trans_date" and "trans_type" and I want to filter this table so that I have just the last transaction for each account. Clearly, I could do something like

```sql
SELECT acct_id, max(trans_date) as trans_date , max(time) as trans_time
FROM transactions 
where transactions_amount = 500 
GROUP BY acct_id ;
```

Is there a way to do this with a single query, hopefully, a generic method that would work with oracle?

Comment: Every RDBMS uses a different dialect of SQL, you shouldn't expect a statement that works on one to work on another, and certainly not all of them. The most basic of queries might, but please don't aimless tag conflicting RDBMS.

Comment: Why do you have `trans_date` **and** `trans_time`? Why not use a single `timestamp` column?

Answer (score 0):

That's typically done using window functions:

```
select acct_id, trans_date, trans_time
from (
  select acct_id, trans_date, trans_time, 
         max(trans_date) over (partition by acct_id) as max_trans_date,
         max(trans_time) over (partition by acct_id) as max_trans_time
  from transactions
  where ...
) t
where trans_date = max_trans_date
  and trans_time = max_trans_time;
```

The above is 100% standard SQL and works on every modern DBMS.

Comment: It should be noted that this approach (contrary to the `row_number = 1` solution) can produce *several* `last transactions` in case of ties...

Answer (score 0):

Use a `row_number` aggregated function as follows

```
row_number() over (partition by acct_id order by trans_date desc) rn
```

list in `PARTITION BY` all columns that identifies the entity (in your case the account id)

on `ORDER BY` define the columns that order the transaction in descended order, so that the last row get the `RN=1`.

Please remember that if it is possible that more transactions can have e.g. identical timestamp, enhance the order columns so, that they with the partition by columns build a *unique key*. This is important to get * deterministic* and *well defined* result.

The final query selects only the rows with `RN=1`

The whole query with sample data

```
with trans as (
select 1 acct_id, date'2020-01-01' trans_date, 'CR' trans_type from dual union all
select 1 acct_id, date'2020-02-11' trans_date, 'DB' trans_type from dual union all
select 1 acct_id, date'2020-03-21' trans_date, 'CR' trans_type from dual union all
select 2 acct_id, date'2020-01-10' trans_date, 'DB' trans_type from dual union all
select 2 acct_id, date'2020-04-01' trans_date, 'CR' trans_type from dual),
trans2 as (
select t.*,
row_number() over (partition by acct_id order by trans_date desc) rn
from trans t)
select ACCT_ID, TRANS_DATE, TRANS_TYPE
from trans2
where rn = 1

   ACCT_ID TRANS_DATE          TR
---------- ------------------- --
         1 21.03.2020 00:00:00 CR
         2 01.04.2020 00:00:00 CR
```